# Como posicionar formulario en pantalla completa en dispositivos móviles

Tags: html, diseño

Tengo el inconveniente de que al abrir mi sitio en dispositivos móviles e formulario de login se ve muy lejos y no en pantalla completa. Quisiera que el formulario se muestre al 100% de la pantalla al abrir el sitio. Mostrare unas imágenes para que entiendan.

Esto es cuando abro el sitio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es como quiero que salga cuando abra el sitio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como han visto lo que necesito es que se muestre al 100% de la pantalla de los móviles y no así alejado.

Comment: Estás utilizando la tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1"> esta es la tag que tengo @KacosPro

Comment: Podrías incluir las partes importantes del código de tu login? :)

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de la pagina que se encarga de dar tamaño a la pagina quizás, sea por eso

Answer (score 0):

si no estas utilizando ninguna librería, deberas usar un meadiaquery, en el cual indiques el cambio de tamaño en la pantalla, por ejemplo

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    div#contenedor-login{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```